# How do I echo column data that is within specific conditions so that it is looped into a html select tag?

Tags: php, html, sql, forms, mysqli

I am trying to loop through a table with specific conditions. For example, I have a table called `user_role_types` and in there I have four columns: `id`, `user_group`, `user_role`, `status`.

I want to display everything in the `user_role` column where the `user_group` is `Front End` and the `status` is *1* into HTML select options.

Here is my **HTML form**:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="">User Type</label>
    <select name="user_role_type[]" id="" class="form-control">
        <?php select(); ?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Here is the **`select()` function:**

```
function select() {

    //DB Connection
    include 'db-con.php';

    // SQL Query
    $sql    =   "SELECT * FROM user_role_types WHERE user_group='Front End' AND status='1'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    $user_role_type = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    $user_role = $user_role_type['user_role'];

    $exp_user_role = explode(",", $user_role); 

    while ($user_role_type = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        foreach ($exp_user_role as $key => $value) {
            echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$value.'</option>';
        }   
    }   
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd start looking into normalization and relational databases, seeing you're using comma-separated values. Those can be a bit of a pain to deal with at times.

Comment: The question never explains what's wrong. Show some sample data, the desired result, and the incorrect result you're getting instead.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem.

What I did was, in the **function**, I removed the `$user_role_type`, `$user_role`, `$exp_user_role` variables. I also removed the `foreach` loop and changed the condition of the `while` loop to:

```
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
```

In the while loop I put this:

```
echo '<option value="'.$row['user_role'].'">'.$row['user_role'].'</option>';
```

This means my whole function code is this:

```
function select() {

    //DB Connection
    include 'db-con.php';

    // SQL Query
    $sql    =   "SELECT * FROM user_role_types WHERE user_group='Front End' AND status='1'";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '<option value="'.$row['user_role'].'">'.$row['user_role'].'</option>';
        }   
    }
```

Comment: You're not splitting up the roles on the comma delimiter any more.

Comment: Why do you use `select *` if you're only using the `user_role` column? Write `SELECT user_rol`.